# Correct notation for uncertain expectation

Tags: expected-value, notation

I need to write some documentation for a couple of process design options. Ultimately, my organization has to find a way to estimate the values of vector $A$.

I have come up with a model to calculate $E(A|B)$, the expected value of $A$ given a known value of $B$.

We do not actual know the value of B up front, but we do know $E(B)$ the expected value of $B$. Through some fiddling of the process we can nail down a value of $B$ but not everyone agrees this is a good idea.

The two options I need to document

1. Fixed $B$ leading to a clean $E(A|B)$. This option has some downsides that are not important here.
2. Unknown $B$ leading to $\int_B E(A|b)f(b)db$.

Is there a standard compact way to represent option 2 that makes it clear that $B$ is unknown and subject to it's own probability distribution?

Comment: Reporting $E(A|B_i)$ for *multiple* $B_i$ is scenario analysis. If you can put probabilities on the $B_i$, this may be easier to communicate.

Comment: In option 2, the integral reduces to $E(A)$. This is the law of iterated expectations.